# Remove newLine from ng-model variable inside textarea

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have `ng-repeat` of textarea in which i am saving text inside of object in array. What i need is when i press `Enter` we create new textarea moving focus on new it and not adding new line on the previous textarea. So what i have is something like this.

```
//Javascript
$scope.texts = [{}];
var addNewLine = function(index){
    var newObj = {};
    // NEXT LINE IS NOT WORKING
    $scope.texts[index].text=$scope.texts[index].text.replace(/\n|\r|\r\n|\n\r/g, '');
    $scope.texts.splice(index+1, 0, newObj);
    $scope.selected = newObj;
}
var removeLine = function(index){
    if(!$scope.texts[index].text||$scope.texts[index].length==0){
        $scope.texts.splice(index, 1);
        if(index==0) $scope.selected = $scope.texts[1];
        else $scope.selected = $scope.texts[index-1];
    }
}
$scope.checkPress = function(event, index){
    if(event.keyCode == 13) addNewLine(index);
    else if(event.keyCode == 8) removeLine(index);
}

//HTML
<textarea ng-repeat="textObj in texts"
ng-model="textObj.text" ng-keyup="checkPress($event, $index)"
focus-if="selected.$$hashKey == textObj.$$hashKey"
ng-click="selected=textObj"></textarea>
```

Where focus-if i am using [THIS PLUGIN](https://github.com/hiebj/ng-focus-if). How can i remove newLine from previous `textarea` when i am adding new `textarea`?

Comment: why are you using `textarea` instead of `input` if you only want to capture a single line of data?  Also, you haven't really asked a question here; is there something not working with your code?

Comment: I need textarea, input is not making two lines when width of container is not enough. The question is why replace is not working, why it's not removing last empty line.

Answer (score 1):

```
<textarea ng-keyup="checkPress($event, $index)"
          ng-keydown="$event.keyCode == 13 && $event.preventDefault()"
          focus-if="selected.$$hashKey == objRow.$$hashKey"
          ng-click="selectText(objRow)">
</textarea>
```

Basically i added prevent default for case of enter and that worked out.